# Find array difference

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays:

```
$network_keys= array(
    (int) 0 => '7 ADELAIDE',
    (int) 1 => '7TWO ADELAIDE'
);

$dblist = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'PrpMedia' => array(
            'id' => (int) 3,
            'network_key' => '7 ADELAIDE',
            'media_id' => (int) 43
        ),
        'Media' => array(
            'id' => (int) 43,
            'media_type_id' => (int) 5,
            'media_location_id' => (int) 4,
            'media_name' => 'Channel 7 ADELAIDE',
            'deleted' => false
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'PrpMedia' => array(
            'id' => (int) 4,
            'network_key' => 'VIC 1HD BENDIGO',
            'media_id' => (int) 42
        ),
        'Media' => array(
            'id' => (int) 42,
            'media_type_id' => (int) 5,
            'media_location_id' => (int) 4,
            'media_name' => '7MATE',
            'deleted' => false
        )
    )
)
```

I want to find which values from `$network_keys` do not exist in `$dbList`.

To be clear, we are looking in `$dblist[0]['PrpMedia']['network_key']`.

Expected array:

```
$difference = array('7TWO ADELAIDE');
```

Comment: no values of `$network_keys` exist in `$sbList`

Comment: don't give sample data, it confuse others.And also tell what you tried till now. The code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a combination of [array_map](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp) and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$diff = array_diff($network_keys, array_map(function($v) {
    return $v['PrpMedia']['network_key'];
}, $dblist));
```

In the example you give, you will get the value of *$network_keys*, because none of them occur in the searched array.

The code first extracts all the `['PrpMedia']['network_key']` values from *$network_keys* into an array that will have the same flat structure as *$dblist*. Then it simply takes the difference, only keeping the elements of *$dblist* that do not occur in that intermediate array.

Be aware that this code assumes the searched key `['PrpMedia']['network_key']` exists in all of the elements of *$network_keys*. If this cannot be assumed to be always the case, then add a check, like this:

```
$diff = array_diff($network_keys, array_map(function($v) {
    return isset($v['PrpMedia']['network_key']) 
        ? $v['PrpMedia']['network_key']
        : null;
}, $dblist));
```

This will also work correctly if the `['PrpMedia']` key is not present for  one of the elements.